# Azure service bus billing

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-billing

Where do I look up in the Azure portal to see how am I getting charged for using the Azure service bus? I have multiple azure bus service instances and I am getting charged about $50 per month. I just don't know how am I getting charged for using this service.

Also is there any way to tell how many messages are we getting on the service bus instance over a month? and compare it with the previous month's count?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the cost per resource in the cost management tab in the Azure portal then in cost analysis

[image]

You could also see the amount of messages in the service bus metrics tab, just filter by incoming messages and there you will see them, this metric is available only for 30 days so you won't be able to see previous months metrics unless you saved them in a storage account or any SIEM.